# How to update paperclip attachment field record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I created an edit form for profile page which contain First Name, Last Name and Photo

```
<%= form_tag "/profiles/update", :html => {:multipart => true} do%>

    <h4>First Name:</h4>
    <%= text_field_tag :first_name, @profile.first_name %>

    <h4>Last Name:</h4>
    <%= text_field_tag :last_name, @profile.last_name %>

    <h4>Photo</h4>
    <%= file_field_tag :photo %>

    <%= submit_tag "Save changes" %>

<% end %>
```

and on update action I put

```
@profile.update_attributes(:first_name => params[:first_name], :last_name => params[:last_name], :photo => params[:photo])
```

So when I run edit form and select new image for file field then submit I got this Error

```
Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError in ProfilesController#update
No handler found for "Pic.jpg"
```

Any suggestions what's the problem here?

Comment: What does the `has_attached_file` block from your `Profile` model look like?

Comment: has_attached_file :photo

Comment: Try defining a thumbnail style. If that makes it work, I would file a bug with the [paperclip project](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip), because defining a style should not be necessary.

Comment: I think that the problem with file_field_tag because in create action when I use "f.file_field" it works fine but when I use file_field_tag on update action It through this error

Comment: Strange. In that case I would just rewrite the form to use `form_for @profile` and go from there.

Comment: Yeah! it works, but do you have any idea why it doesn't work with form_tag ?? Am I restricted to use form_for ??

Comment: I don't. It may be worth raising an issue on github about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
<%= form_tag "/products/create", :multipart => true do%>
```

It will work fine now